# How do I justify a horizontal list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, justify

I have a horizontal navbar like the following:

```
<ul id = "Navigation">
    <li><a href = "About.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href = "Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

I use CSS to remove the bullet points and make it horizontal.

```
#Navigation li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

I'm trying to justify the text so each link is spread out evenly to fill up the entirety of the `ul`'s space.  I tried adding `text: justify` to both the `li` and `ul` selectors, but they're still left-aligned.

```
#Navigation
{
    text-align: justify;
}

#Navigation li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

This is strange, because if I use `text-align: right`, it behaves as expected.

How do I spread out the links evenly?

Comment: will the number of `<li>` elements be variable?

Comment: Then Mr thirtydot is the person to see.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### Modern Approach - [CSS3 Flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

Now that we have [CSS3 flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), you no longer need to resort to tricks and workarounds in order to make this work. Fortunately, [browser support has come a long way](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), and most of us can start using flexboxes.

Just set the parent element's `display` to `flex` and then change the [`justify-content` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) to either [`space-between`](http://jsfiddle.net/sdaq97hh/) or [`space-around`](http://jsfiddle.net/y96j80cy/) in order to add space between/around the children flexbox items. Then add additional vendor prefixes for [more browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

**Using `justify-content: space-between`** - [(**example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/sdaq97hh/):

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Contact Longer Link</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Using `justify-content: space-around`** - [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/y96j80cy/):

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Contact Longer Link</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how to make it compatible with IE9?

Comment: `justify-content: center` also works. The advantage of that is that you can still use `float: left` to have control over the spacing of the list items per `margin-left`.

Answer (score 35):

You need to use a "trick" to make this work.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/2kRJv/

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="Navigation">
    <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <!-- ... -->
    <li class="stretch"></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#Navigation
{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 21px;
    background: #ccc
}

#Navigation li
{
    display: inline
}
#Navigation .stretch {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;

    /* if you need IE6/7 support */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
```

Details on IE6/7 trickery: [Inline block doesn't work in internet explorer 7, 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575)

Comment: @Maxpm: `text-align: justify` [only works](http://jsfiddle.net/R4449/) when you have more than one line of "text" (or in this case, the `li`s that are `inline`). So, another "line" (`.stretch`) is added. `display: inline-block` allows `width: 100%` to work.

Comment: Heads up - this method kind of freaks out (full-width justifies) if you have more than one word inside each `<li>` too from what I can tell.

Comment: just a note, that question was asked 2 years ago, but now i believe most will agree that justify is evil in most cases, and should be avoided. Think about really wide block...

Comment: @JoshuaStewardson: Fortunately, that's quite easy to fix: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/2kRJv/822/. I just noticed that someone else also posted the same fix much earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879467/how-do-i-justify-a-horizontal-list/14649908#14649908.

Comment: You can now use `#Navigation:after` in place of `#Navigation .strech`, and dump the extra `<li>`.

Comment: Note for PHP coders: You may need to concatenate "\n" at the end of your "<li>"'s if your using a php condition to output html. Otherwise if your outputting html in a single blob, it will not work.

Answer (score 26):

This can also be achieved using a pseudo element on the `ul` element:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: justify;
}

ul:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I know this is old now, but maybe you shouldn't use LESS unless it's within the scope of the question.. Could be confusing to others. Other than that, great alternative to thirtydot's answer, +1

Comment: Good point - to be honest I hadn't even noticed (been a while since I wrote plain ol'CSS). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Love this, much cleaner and less hacky than the accepted answer.

Comment: @gordian: This answer and my answer are virtually the same. The exact same technique is used, the only difference is trivial. I was trying to support IE7 (doesn't support `:after`) which was something I cared about back in 2011.

Comment: +1 make sure you have spaces between your li elements, or it won't justify

Answer (score 5):

Just do:

```
ul { width:100%; }
ul li {
  display:table-cell;
  width:1%;
}
```

Comment: You should separate your code from your text, improve the code formatting and explain in a sentence what the CSS does.

Comment: While other solutions (not the flexbox one) works only with single word menu links, this one works perfectly! thank you.

Comment: Kindly explain the meaning for width:1%

Answer (score 4):

This might suit your needs:

```
#Navigation{
}
#Navigation li{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 50%; /*if 2 <li> elements, 25% if 4...*/
}
```

**demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/KmqzQ/

Comment: Works nicely with the obvious caveat that you must set the correct `width` :)

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<ul id="Navigation">
    <li><a href="#">The Missing Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Riluri</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <!-- ... -->
    <li class="stretch"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#Navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 21px;
    background: #ccc
}

#Navigation li{
    display: inline
}

#Navigation li a {
    text-align: left;
    display:inline-block;
}

#Navigation .stretch {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;

    /* if you need IE6/7 support */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
```

View demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2kRJv/392/

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the <li> elements separated, otherwise the justify won't work.

```
For example, this:

<ul><li>test</li><li>test</li></ul>


needs to be like this:
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
```

or at least have spaces between the opening and closing <li> tags.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](http://code.jelmerdemaat.nl/2012/perfectly-justified-css-grid-technique-using-inline-block/) has a satisfyingly robust solution. It needs some slight changes to accommodate a `ul/li` navigation, though:

```
#Navigation {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 0;
    font-size: 12px\9; /* IE 6-9 */
}
#Navigation>li {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline; /* IE only */
}
#Navigation:after {
    content:"";
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/9vNBs/

Answer (score 0):

The marked answer does not work if  has a white space in it.

The top answer here works with white spaces
[How do I *really* justify a horizontal menu in HTML+CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536/how-do-i-really-justify-a-horizontal-menu-in-htmlcss)

Answer (score 0):

**Using CSS Flexboxes**

```
#Navigation {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: .5rem 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```