# How to achieve the float:right effect while preserving the inline-block display?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/yqdJG/1/

#### HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="char">
        AAA
    </div>
    <div class="char stickToRight">
        BBB
    </div>
</div>​
```

#### CSS:

```
#container {
    border:solid 2px green
}
.char { 
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 2px red;
}
.stickToRight {
    float: right
}​
```

Is there another way to make `.stickToRight` be aligned right, *without floating it?*

I need to keep it as `display:inline-block` so that I can make its vertical alignment consistent with other `.char` elements.

How can I achieve the `float:right` right-alignment effect, whilst keeping the element `display:inline-block`? (Note that I do not know the width of the container element.)

I'd like purely CSS solutions, if there are any.

Comment: it is already stick to right, n DIV is an out line element, therefore its display is always block,

Comment: `float` will make the element have it's own "special `display: float`" behind the scenes. It doesn't matter whether you declare it as a `block`, `inline-block`, or even `table-cell` for that matter.

Comment: add `float:left;` to `.char` class.

Comment: I need display inline-block, how adding float:left to .char helps me?

Comment: Could you describe your visual requirements in a little more detail? Why do you need `.stickToRight` to be inline-block? What visual effect are you going for?

Comment: Added the motivation section to the post.

Answer (score 22):

I was having the same problem, and found out using `direction: rtl;` on the container is the best solution. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/

Comment: This is the best solution - came here to say this. Heres a quick example of a case where I used something like this. Doesn't match the example exactly but you get the idea. This allowed me to keep the structure the same in both cases so that on mobile (when I would display the image above) both examples would look the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/uku099g8/

Comment: Genius! Works just the way it's supposed to.

Comment: Well, this messes up all the texts if you have other textual elements in the parent.

Answer (score 17):

An element can’t be `inline-block` and floated at the same time.

When an element is set to `inline-block`, it differs from `display:inline` elements in that it can have a width and height specified. However, it’s still part of the inline layout flow — its horizontal position is determined by its source order and the `text-align` property of its block-level parent, and its vertical position with the line is determined by the `vertical-align` property.

When an element is floated, it’s no longer part of the inline layout flow. Its horizontal position is determined by whether it’s floated `left` or `right`, and whether there are other floated elements before it, and its vertical position is determined by a fairly involved set of rules that Eric Meyer describes really well in *CSS: the Definitive Guide*, but that basically boil down to “the top of the inline box in which it would have appeared if it wasn’t floated”.

I’m still not quite sure what visual effect you’re imagining when you say you want the element to be floated and `inline-block` at the same time, but float layout is different from `inline-block` layout in terms of both horizontal and vertical position, and there isn’t any way to combine them.

Comment: I did not say I wanted them floating. I want them aligned to the right. How it is achieved does not matter.

Comment: I am OK with it, if it conveys the message better.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @PaulD.Waite very useful. I want the same effect which basically is: keep the element floated but make it break into a new line (like a block element would) if it must. Currently my floated element breaks our of its parent div.

Comment: The way I am currently achieving the effect is by making the *parent* element 'display: inline-block; width: 100%' but this might be specific to my case.

Comment: @Dimitris: “make it break into a new line (like a block element would) if it must”. There’s a bunch of complexity hidden in “if it must”. Anyhoo, if you’re having trouble trying to achieve something with CSS, that’s what the “Ask Question” button is for.

Comment: I don't see a need to duplicate this question. "How to achieve the float:right effect while preserving the inline-block display?" is exactly what I would ask.

Answer (score 9):

Since the `inline` element can not `float`, we can not build some complicate layout. Then [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) was introduced and now we have a powerful technology can solve most layout problems. To achieve your expected result, just do simply like this:

```css
#container {
  border: solid 2px green;
  display: flex;
}

.char {
  border: solid 2px red;
  ;
}

.float-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="char ">
    AAA
  </div>
  <div class="char float-right">
    BBB
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Apply `text-align: right` to parent div

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align to the right of its parent an element without using float, you can go for the CSS3 box-flex property. Here is a post with an example on how to use it :
[How to align on the right an inline-block element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202607/how-to-align-on-the-right-an-inline-block-element)

Mark that it's a CSS3 solution and therefore not compatible with all browsers (point at IE9-)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would avoid `float: right` and tabled displays at all costs, but that's my preference. I haven't found a better way to do this other than resorting to the necessary evil that is absolute positioning. Although, for this purpose, it might make `display: inline-block` useless, it usually gives the desired effect in these scenarios. An example would be (using your code as a guideline) a header, with the logo positioned as if "floating" left, and `ul` positioned as if "floating" right.

```
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
        <ul>
          <li> Link 1 </li>
          <li> Link 2 </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

The basic CSS being:

```
   .container {
     max-width: 1200px;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     position: relative;
     padding: 0 15px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   .container h1 {
     display: inline-block;
   }
   .container ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      right: 15px; /* I use 15px to replicate the 15px padding on the container*/
   }
   .container ul li {
      display: inline-block;
   }
```

This is the scenario where I use this code most often. In most cases in the content I have percentage widths for my containers, removing the need (most of the time) for positioning. IE:

```
       <div class="container">
          <div class="left"></div>
          <div class="right"></div>
       </div>


       .container {
           max-width: 1200px;
           width: 100%;
           margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .left {
           display: inline-block;
           width: 60%;
           margin-right: -4px; /* I use this because I've noticed a 4px spacing when using inline block sometimes */
        }
        .right {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 40%;
          margin-right: -4px;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

It may be too late to help with this, but just in case someone stumbles on this, here you go. Paul D. Waite, answered the source of your problem.
I think I know what you're trying to achieve. I have done something "wrong" to accomplish that just in case you're desperate and you want to avoid Flexbox. 
Keep your last element inline-block, and float: right. and add this to it.
.last-element-in-your-row

```
{
display: inline-block;
float: right;
/*add this to stick that guy on the right*/
position: relative;
right: 0;
top: 0;}
```

Again this is not the right way, but it works...

Comment: you'll want to set the display: inline-block, your code wont actually do anything.

Comment: `float: right` will overwrite `display: inline-block`  since float can only be applied to an inline element

Comment: Sour_Tooth. you are right. That was a mistake from my side. Thanks