# align a horizontals menu li items

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am having real troubles with trying to align a horizontal menu.So far my menu is looking like
[image]

I have 2 centered elements to make up the menu in the image you can see a gray border (slide-nav class) that has been centered within the page. Now I am trying to do the same for the menu

I have had to hard code the li widths but ideally I would like them to fit automatically. Is it possible without javascript to align the menu items in the center?

My html

```
   <nav class="slide-nav">
            <ul class="slider">
                <li class="selected">
                    <div>
                        <span class="heart"></span>
                        <div>
                            Get Started</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <span class="price-tag"></span>
                        <div>
                            Get Results</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <span class="star"></span>
                        <div>
                            Track & Engage</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <span class="people"></span>
                        <div>
                            Features</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

css

```
.slide-nav
{
border-bottom: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 856px;
}
.slider
{
list-style: none;
height: 38px; 
margin: 0 auto;
width: 722px;
}
.slider li
{
border-bottom: solid 7px transparent;
cursor: pointer;

display: inline-block;
width: 150px;
}
.slider li div 
{
line-height: 31px; 
}
.slider li div div 
{
text-indent: 6px;
}
.slider li.selected > div
{
border-bottom: solid 7px #592970;

}
```

Comment: Please provide us an example via http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the CSS that u have to change with

```
.slide-nav
{
border-bottom: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 856px;
text-align:center;
}
.slider
{
list-style: none;
height: 38px; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.slider li
{
border-bottom: solid 7px transparent;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
padding:0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got rid of the widths, removed `margin: 0 auto` from `.slider` and added the ole `text-align: center`.

Check out a live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/RJL7J/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been answered in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536/how-do-i-really-justify-a-horizontal-menu-in-htmlcss).

Basically you want to have your individual buttons rendered with `display:inline-block` which would allow for them to be justified. There's a trick however with adding a "dummy" line break to force justification.