# "text-align: justify;" inline-block elements properly?

Tags: css, text-align, justify

A few other questions have already addressed how best to apply `text-align: justify` to get inline-block elements to spread out evenly… for example, [How do I *really* justify a horizontal menu in HTML+CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536/how-do-i-really-justify-a-horizontal-menu-in-htmlcss)

However, the 100% width element that "clears" the line of inline-block elements is given its own line by the browser. I can't figure out how to get rid of that empty vertical space without using `line-height: 0;` on the parent element.

For an example of the problem, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89bnF/)

For my solution that uses `line-height: 0;`, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89bnF/1/)

The solution I'm using requires that a new `line-height` be applied to the child elements, but any previously set `line-height` is lost. Is anyone aware of a better solution? I want to avoid tables so that the elements can wrap when necessary, and also flexbox because the browser support isn't there yet. I also want to avoid floats because the number of elements being spaced out will be arbitrary.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

***Updated the "Future" solution info below; still not yet fully supported.***

### Present Workaround (IE8+, FF, Chrome Tested)

[**See this fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/89bnF/77/)

**Relevant CSS**

```css
.prevNext {
    text-align: justify;
}

.prevNext a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 1.2em; /* your line-height */
}

.prevNext:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -1.2em; /* your line-height */
}

.prevNext:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Explanation**

The `display: block` on the `:before` element with the negative bottom margin pulls the lines of text up one line height which eliminates the extra line, but displaces the text. Then with the `position: relative` on the `inline-block` elements the displacement is counteracted, but without adding the additional line back.

Though css cannot directly access a `line-height` "unit" per se, the use of `em` in the `margin-bottom` and `top` settings easily accommodates any `line-height` given as one of the [multiplier values](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height). So `1.2`, `120%`, or `1.2em` are all *equal* in calculation *with respect to `line-height`*, which makes the use of `em` a good choice here, as even if `line-height: 1.2` is set, then `1.2em` for `margin-bottom` and `top` will match. Good coding to normalize the look of a site means at some point `line-height` should be defined explicitly, so if any of the multiplier methods are used, then the equivalent `em` unit will give the same value as the `line-height`. And if `line-height` is set to a non-`em` length, such as `px`, that instead could be set.

Definitely having a variable or mixin using a css preprocessor such as LESS or SCSS could help keep these values matching the appropriate `line-height`, or javascript could be used to dynamically read such, but really, the `line-height` should be known in the context of where this is being used, and the appropriate settings here made.

**UPDATE for minified text (no spaces) issue**

Kubi's comment noted that a minification of the html that removes the spaces between the `<a>` elements [causes the justification to fail](http://jsfiddle.net/QaS5J/1/). A [pseudo-space within the `<a>` tag does not help](http://jsfiddle.net/QaS5J/4/) (but that is expected, as the space is happening inside the `inline-block` element), a [`<wbr>` added between the `<a>` tags does not help](http://jsfiddle.net/QaS5J/5/) (probably because a break is not necessary to the next line), so if minification is desired, then [the solution is a hard coded non-breaking space character `&nbsp;`](http://jsfiddle.net/QaS5J/6/)--other space characters like [thin space](http://jsfiddle.net/QaS5J/8/) and [en space](http://jsfiddle.net/QaS5J/9/) did not work (surprisingly).

### Nearing a Future Clean Solution

[A solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-align-last) in which [`webkit` was behind the times](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76173) (as of first writing this) was:

```
.prevNext {
    text-align: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: justify;
    -webkit-text-align-last: justify; /* not implemented yet, and will not be */
    text-align-last: justify; /* IE */
}
```

[It works in FF 12.0+ and IE8+](http://jsfiddle.net/89bnF/44/) (buggy in IE7).

For Webkit, as of version 39 (at least, might have crept in earlier) it does support it ***without*** the `-webkit-` extension but ***only* if the *user* has enabled the experimental features** (which can be done at `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`). Rumor is that version 41 or 42 should see full support. Since it is not seamlessly supported by `webkit` yet, ***it is still only a partial solution***. However, I thought I should post it as it can be useful for some.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas--not according to the first link I posted. I have not officially checked it myself.

Comment: I like both solutions, although the lack of Webkit and Opera support is a killer for the second solution. For the first solution, I'm trying to avoid specifically designating the line-height and make it a . If there's a way to do `margin-bottom: (1 unit of inherited line-height);` and `top: (more of the same);` then it might work best…

Comment: @thirdender--css cannot access a `line-height` "unit" per se, but I've edited the "Explanation" information in my answer, which may help resolve your worries there about this method.

Comment: It took me an hour to figure out that this method will *only work if you have whitespace* in between your child elements. It did not work with my xsl-generated `formatOutput = true` "minified" HTML. Cf. http://jsfiddle.net/QaS5J/1/
A chain of no-whitespace inline-blocks is treated like a word, I guess, and therefore not justified.

Comment: @kubi: Excellent observation and comment. I am a bit surprised that the `inline-block` setting itself does not trigger it as a word division, but I guess since it is partially an `inline` element, the browser must figure that if no whitespace exists, the intent is to be wrapping elements of a word itself (characters), and thus does not introduce its own word break.

Comment: @kubi: There is a work around if minification of html is desired. I've updated my answer. Basically, a hard coded non-breaking space in the html is needed (which should not be eliminated in minifying).

Comment: Just a little note on the `nbsp;` between the elements. Adding an `nbsp;` causes a tiny offset in the positioning of the inline-blocks. To prevent that, wrap every `nbsp;` in a`span.inivisible-space` and create a class with `font-size: 0;`

Comment: In **IE**, it will only work if the container (in this case **.prevNext**) have a font-size property greater than 0. If it is equals 0, then it won't work

Comment: GREAT catch on the minified HTML problem. Otherwise, the most reliable solution for white-space is simply `font-size: 0` on the parent, and `font-size: 1rem` on the children (the inline-blocks)

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following:

```
.prevNext {
    display: table;
    width: 100%
}

.prevNext a {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center
}
```

​(Also see the [edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89bnF/79/).) Is that what you are looking for? The advantage of this technique is that you can add more items and they will all be centered automatically. Supported by all modern Web browsers.

Comment: This technique isn't the magic solution it appears to be if you have content of unequal length.  I modified the fiddle to show this.    You can clearly see that the spacing around the short links is much less than around the long links.   http://jsfiddle.net/arkid77/5vcgpkeL/2/

Comment: Not exactly 'Justified'.

Answer (score 4):

First off, I like the approach of the `pseudo-element` in order to keep the markup semantic.  I think you should stick with the overall approach.  It's far better than resorting to tables, unnecessary markup, or over the top scripts to grab the positioning data.

For everyone stressed about `text-align` being hacky - c'mon!  It's better that the html be semantic at the expense of the CSS than vice versa.

So, from my understanding, you're trying to achieve this justified inline-block effect without having to worry about resetting the `line-height` every time right?  I contend that you simply add

```
.prevNext *{
    line-height: 1.2;  /* or normal */
}
```

Then you can go about coding as though nothing happened.  Here's Paul Irish's quote about the `*` selector if you're worried about performance:

"...you are not allowed to care about the performance of * unless you concatenate all your javascript, have it at the bottom, minify your css and js, gzip all your assets, and losslessly compress all your images. If you aren't getting 90+ Page Speed scores, it's way too early to be thinking about selector optimization."

Hope this helps!

-J Cole Morrison

Comment: I am really liking the `line-height: normal;` :-p It dovetails nicely with what I was trying to do. It doesn't get rid of the `line-height: 0;`, but resets the line-height to a normalized value. If someone else wants to override the line-height they can… Still trying to grok @MoinZaman's Sitepoint link, and hoping there might be some other answer that doesn't require the `line-height: 0;`, but this feels close.

Comment: Hey Thirdender!  Yeah, I looked through some of the different things, but often I've found that, especially for CSS, the simplest approach works best.  It's nice that changing around the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` works, but those lead to an even wider array of potential descendant css conflicts. Go for maintainable and understandable in my opinion (and pray for `flexbox`)!

Comment: It _might_ help performance some to use: `.prevNext > *` so it is only looking at the direct children rather than _all_ descendents of `.prevNext`. Of course, this is still a `line-height` reset, which in the question the OP said he was trying to avoid.

Comment: Agreed on the performance thing!  With respect to the reset issue: The OP asks IF there's a better solution and seeks to avoid tables, flexbox, and floats - not specifically a line-height reset.

Comment: Yes… I was trying to avoid a line-height reset (because it should inherit from the parent elements), but even more importantly I was trying to avoid specifying a fixed line-height. `line-height: 1.2em` or `line-height: 1.2` is _close_ to `line-height: normal`, but each font defines it's own 'normal' line-height, so 1.2 is only an approximation. I didn't realize `line-height: normal` was available as an option (I tried 'default' and 'auto', but missed 'normal' in my Google searches). I'd still like a better solution, but I think this works in 9/10 use cases (which works for my SCSS mixin).

Comment: Gotcha, my bad.  For this new solution are you looking for something more "semantically" correct or something more "simple" out of curiosity?

Comment: @thirdender--I don't believe fonts explicitly define 'normal'. The [spec states](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height) that `normal`: "Tells user agents to set the used value to a 'reasonable' value based on the font of the element," and further recommended to be "between 1.0 to 1.2." So the _browser_ is setting the `normal` value based off a backend calculation that involves the font. This is why it is good to explicitly set `line-height`, as it helps standardize the cross browser experience and give ["vertical rhythm"](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/).

Comment: "For obscure reasons rooted in the history of the TrueType and OpenType font formats, every webfont carries three sets of linespacing values." [source](http://webfonts.info/webfonts-know-how/part-2-problem-line-height) That value is taken into consideration when calculating the `line-height: normal;`, but that is also the direct cause of the "vertical rhythm" issues. I'm assuming in most cases when line-height is crucial to layout, it will (or can) be specified inside whatever area this CSS is applied to.

Comment: @thirdender--good source reference. I think we are on the same page, that the font defines something in _itself_ which the browser through some "backend calculation" (to quote myself) uses to actually define `normal`. You were emphasizing the font's role, I was emphasizing the browser's role, but I think we end up at the same place: `normal` is not explicit based off font or browser independently, but only in combination.

Comment: Yeah, the important thing is that not all fonts have the same line-height. I think that was intentional to deal with different font rendering systems (look at the history of Windows vs Mac font rendering…). So if you're attempting a layout with "vertical rhythm", your line-height should be set as close to the content as possible. Since the `text-align: justify` part is used for layout, I can see `line-height` being set explicitly after this in the CSS. I'd still like to get rid of the `line-height: 0`, but without needing to pass in an explicit line-height from the parent elements.

Comment: For sure!  As diverse web typography becomes more and more center-stage getting away from odd uses of `text-align` and friends will be harder to `justify` (haha!).  I wish they'd call `text-align` `inline-align` or something.  `getComputedStyle` is a fun API to hook into if you need to read up on the current state of an element if the typography is changing.  Just remember the shortest distance between two points is a straight-line - don't get too caught up in everything being syntactically/semantically perfect.  Utopian coding in a dystopian environment is ... ?

Comment: I'll probably use `line-height: normal` in my SCSS mixin, but I'm really hoping to use `text-align-last: justify` as mentioned in the accepted answer soon. Some years from now, it'd be great for all browsers to implement the new CSS3 flexbox standard, but in the meantime… It looks like `text-align-last: justify` will work in all browsers as far back as IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to `text-align` for this problem is pretty hackish.  The `text-align` property is meant to align inline content of a block (specifically text) -- it is not meant to align html elements.

I understand that you are trying to avoid floats, but in my opinion floats are the best way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing; it's misusing one property for the sake of not using another property that is actually made for this very purpose.

Comment: @VinnyBurgh--I would tend to disagree. Floats are not designed to "justify" elements on a line. Floats can be forced to pseudo-justify elements, but only if fixed widths are involved. His use case demands allowing for more than just two elements, one right, one left, based off his comment to Ali Gajani's answer. It also appears to not involve fixed width elements.

Comment: I agree that floats aren't designed to justify elements, but text-align:justify isn't designed for that purpose either. Both properties were introduced in CSS1 and I'm sure this sort of use-case wasn't appropriate nor necessary at the time of their writing. I am enjoying the OP's question, regardless.

Comment: @VinnyBurgh, the new [CSS3 flexbox standard] (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) fills the bill perfectly, but the last flexbox implementation fell short and never had IE support (aside from a JS shim which gave me some issues)…

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have `line-height:1.2`, without a unit. This may cause issues. If you're not using borders you could give the parent and the children a `line-height` of `0`.

The other options I can think of are:

1. Use `display:table` on the parent and `display:table-cell` on the children to simulate table like behaviour. And you align the first item left, and the last one right. See this [fiddle](http://www.jsbin.com/ehiqun/1/edit).
2. Use javascript to do a count of the nav children and then give them a equally distributed width. eg. 4 children, 25% `width` each. And align the first and last items left and right respectively.
3. There is a way to evenly distribute the items but is a convoluted method that requires some non breaking spaces to be carefully placed in the html along with a negative margin and `text-align:justify`. You could try and adapt it the the `nav` element. See example [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?862140-Justify-links-in-horizontal-menu&s=5b5d405f8c94600622fa5af0ecdbd313&p=5139534&viewfull=1#post5139534).

Comment: The borders are just there to display the bounding box of the parent container. Also, giving all elements `line-height: 0` is a bad idea for layout (it can cause the text to render over the previous and next siblings, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyudd/)).

For #1, as mentioned in the question, I'm trying to avoid tables so the elements can wrap if necessary.

For #2, really trying to avoid Javascript and make this a pure CSS solution. I want something I can roll out, set and forget, and not worry about if/when Javascript is available.

Comment: @thirdender--found a workaround solution that should meet your needs and updated my answer to show it.

Comment: @MoinZaman, neither of your links work… They both point to http://www.jsbin.com/edison/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is awfully specific. It seems to me for your case this CSS would work well:

```
.prevNext {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    height: 1.5em;
}

.prevNext a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.prevNext a:first-child {
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.prevNext a:last-child {
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Scotts, the following has been implemented inside Chrome, without the `-webkit` part , which I really loved btw, specially since we need to get rid of the `-browser-specific-shǐt` real soon.

```
.prevNext {
    text-align: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: justify;
    -webkit-text-align-last: justify; /* not implemented yet, and will not be */
    text-align-last: justify; /* IE + Chrome */
}
```

**Note:** Though still the Safari and Opera [don't support it yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-align-last) (08-SEPT-16).

Answer (score -2):

I think the best way would be to create the clickable element with a specific `class`/`id` and then assign `float:left` or `float:right` accordingly. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid floats… For the fiddle I linked floats would work because there are only two elements ("previous", "next"). I created a [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89bnF/7/) showing 4 elements. The goal is to work with any number of elements.