# <li>s don't evenly distribute using justify method

Tags: html, css, html-lists, text-align, justify

I'm attempting to create a navigation bar for a website I'm building. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13505797/3042952) answer among others and still have been unable to get it to work. Instead of distributing the items horizontally, it extends each one to take up the entire line.

My goal is the same as that of the previous question, to dynamically and evenly distribute menu items horizontally such that if I add another item I don't have to manually change anything other than adding the new `<li>`. Here's a JSFiddle showing the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/u7y2zjnm/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
li.navbar {
...
color: #ffffff
...
}
```

by

```
color: #ffffff;
```

you forgot the '`;`'

Comment: Thanks! That's the result of me switching between Python/Lua and PHP/CSS lol

Comment: One other thing, after doing that in the JSFiddle it's distributed but there's a bunch of space before the first item but not after the last. How do I even it out, preferably by adding space to the end?

Comment: ul comes naturally with margin and padding.  Just zero them out on your ul and the space before the first item will disappear.

Comment: Thanks, @haltersweb. That did it.