# CSS - Multiple Columns with min-width & max-width

Tags: html, fluid-layout, css

I'm having a bit of a "moment" where I am stumped on an issue I thought should be pretty easy (and probably is, I'm just over complicating I'm sure).

I'm looking to have a `div` with multiple children `div's`; the children should automatically expand or contract based on the number there are (the site I'm working on is in a CMS that allows a user to add or remove items).

My issue is having the `div's` respect the min- and max-width declaration. I have a hunch that it could be something to do with them being `float:left`, but I've tried a few other variations with no luck.

**My main objective is to get these columns to fill their space on one "row", up to 4 columns.**

***EDIT:*** I need to have these columns be a minimum width, as well as a maximum width. So if there are 3 child `div's`, they should all be wider than if there were 4 child `div's`.

Here is an example of my code: http://codepen.io/joe/full/IJvGp

**HTML**

```
<div class="sub cf">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
          Column 1
      </div>

    <div class="col">
        Column 2
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        Column 3
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        Column 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sub {
  width: 670px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 10px solid #414042;
}

.sub .row {
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.sub .row .col {
  min-width: 166px;
  max-width: 222px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #D0D2D3; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.cf::before, .cf::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.cf::after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: You gave them each a width of 100%. If you want to fit 4 of them in one row, you'd have to give each a width of something like 25%.

Comment: This isn't necessarily easy in CSS. Probably the most straight-forward options are `display: table;` (see [Use CSS display:table for Layout](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout), not supported by IE until IE8), or the new [CSS3 Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) (however, this currently has even less browser support :-p When it does become available, it will be fantastic…).

Comment: +1 for giving a try at `display: table`, with or without `table-layout: fixed` for 2 different algorithms. One based on (relative) width of content, the other on widths you indicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jquery you could dynamically set the column widths as a % based on the number of columns within the row.

```
var colWidth = (1 / $('.sub.cf .row').children().length * 100) + '%';
$('.sub.cf .col').outerWidth(colWidth);​
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/JkK2K/1/).  Insert or remove more columns and rerun it to see how it works.

Comment: As much as I would like to not use jQuery for this, I think it is smarter. Only 2 lines is alright in my book. Thanks for the succinct code and clever solution.

Comment: Since users can add and remove columns, you'll never be able to account for the number you have, so you'll probably need js for this.  I understand wanting to use css only here, but as long as you're already using jquery elsewhere, you're not really bloating too much here. Glad it helped.

Comment: That's what I learned. My hope was that using min- & max-width, it would be at least min-, but no more than max-; oh well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `width:100%;` on the `.sub .row .col` item made them appear in 4 columns.

Regardless it looks like you should be using a table instead of this approach.

Comment: True about using a table. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

### CSS3 Solution

Remove the `min` and `max` widths on `.col` but add the `box-sizing: border-box` property to that. Then add the following code below the `.col` definition which [yields the result in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTwQb/3/):

```
.sub .row .col:nth-last-of-type(2),
.sub .row .col:nth-last-of-type(2) ~ .col
{
   width: 50%;
}

.sub .row .col:nth-last-of-type(3),
.sub .row .col:nth-last-of-type(3) ~ .col
{
   width: 33.3%;
}

.sub .row .col:nth-last-of-type(4),
.sub .row .col:nth-last-of-type(4) ~ .col
{
   width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: ScottS - this looks great, except I have to support down to IE7. It's just as practical to use this code, although it is effective.

Comment: @motoxer4533: Okay, thanks for the input. Since you were using pseudo-elements, I would not have guessed you were supporting down to IE7 (since it does not recognize them), and since you were using the double colon on the pseudo-elements, it appeared you did not care about IE8 either. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Gotcha. It's a clearfix (http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) that I removed some of the code for this specific example.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="sub">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sub {
    text-align: justify;
    width: 670px;
    background: #fff;
    sborder: 10px solid #414042;
}

.sub div {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 166px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border-right: 1px solid #D0D2D3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sub:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, and one of my favorites :-p My question re: this technique is up at [“text-align: justify;” inline-block elements properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589590/text-align-justify-inline-block-elements-properly) The problem I was having was that the `:after` clearing element was creating a whitespace one line of text high.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is `width: 100%` and `max-width: 222px`. With `width: 100%` you are making the children divs as big as you can. And because of `max-width: 222px` they all become 222px width. Your parent div is 670px width, so if you do the math: `222px * 4 = 888px`. The children divs' total width is exceeding the parent's width, that's why it's pulling the last div down.

You can try:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/oIxKF)

If you don't care much about supporting IE8- then ScottS solution is the best.

Answer (score -1):

You have the following code.

```
max-width:222px;
```

Reduce it to some value so that it can be accomdated!

```
max-width:166px;
```

works for me!

Comment: The issue with this is that there is not always 4 columns; this approach will not work.

Comment: When will this not have 4 columns?