# CSS: in absolute list each li Element +x Pixel

Tags: html, css, list, statistics

my goal is to create a Statistic Bar.
To create this, i use a list which has position:absolute to have a vertical List. 
My problem is that - because of the absolut position-  i have to give each li tag +50 Pixel, so that they are not overlapped.

Maybe someone has an idea or a better code snipped for this ;)

HTML

```
<div class="statisticWrapper">
  <div class="barWrapper">
   <ul>
    <li class="element1"  style="height:0%"></li>
    <li class="element2"  style="height:0%"></li>
    <li class="element3" style="height:100%;"><span>1056</span></li>
    <li class="element4" style="height:30%"></li>
   <li class="element5" style="height:0%"></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS Code

```
.statisticWrapper{float:left; width:494px; height:250px; margin-left:8px;}
.statisticWrapper .barWrapper{float:left; width:494px; height:210px;  position:relative;}
.statisticWrapper .barWrapper ul > li {position: absolute; width: 40px; bottom:0px; background-color:#ccc;}

statisticWrapper .barWrapper li.element2{margin-left:50px;}
statisticWrapper .barWrapper li.element3{margin-left:100px;}
statisticWrapper .barWrapper li.element4{margin-left:150px;}
statisticWrapper .barWrapper li.element5{margin-left:200px;}
```

The code actually works, but when i want to have a responsive site, i have to change the margins in each media query and so.. There have to be a better method to solve my problem :(

This is what i actually have: http://skruffes.bplaced.net/test.html

This is what i want:
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide an online demo to demonstrate the problem in action?

Comment: What @HashemQolami meant is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eq9fjdhe/ You can play with the code, save, and then re-share it with us. Can you provide a picture/drawing (using ms-paint) of what you want to achieve?

Comment: oh of course. http://skruffes.bplaced.net/test.html   my goal is to set a auto margin to each li so that they are evenly spaced at the .barWrapper

Comment: this is, what i want to have http://skruffes.bplaced.net/goal.png

Comment: and here is de jsfiddle file http://jsfiddle.net/eq9fjdhe/1/

Comment: I ended up with http://jsbin.com/qucabe/1/edit you may find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to float `li` elements to left and move `position: relative;` from `.barWrapper` to `li` element. Then position `span` with bar label absolutely from bottom. Then you can forget about any additional classes or anything for individual bar.

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/z1xevz3d/)

Note: I've removed unnecessary code and added `<em>`s to position bar label on the bottom to make it look better.

EDIT: If you want label to be over the bar as in your picture simply change `bottom: 0;` to `bottom: 100%` in `em` styling - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/z1xevz3d/2/)

**UPDATE:**
Or you can do that even better by setting `display: inline-block;` to `li` so then you can set height directly on `li` not on inner `span` as in my first solution so you don't need additional element. `em` is used only to get labels over the bar.

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/z1xevz3d/3/)

Comment: thank you very much! What should i do, to make a automatic margin between the different li's so that they take the 100% width of the barWrapper?

Comment: You need to justify your elements. As all `li`s are in the same line then you need to add `text-align-last: justify;` (`-moz-text-align-last: justify;` for FF) for `ul`. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/z1xevz3d/5/). Unfortunately it doesn't work in some WebKit browsers - Safari and Opera(?). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11619432/3589528) you have great cross-browser solution :)

Comment: thanks. i will try it :)   there is only one problem left. when the height of each li is 0% the <em> tags are - of course - at the top. In the future, there should be icons under the bars so, i need to position the em's also on the bottom.

Comment: You need all '%' to be under the chart or only those with 0 value?

Comment: ok i could fix it :)  please try the text-align:justify part in chrome. if i use the normal fixes for this like ul > li:after.. it only reverse the last bar.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use `vertical-align` and `display:inline-block` or even `inline-table` to go a bit further.

`gradient` and `box-shadow` can help too to improve styling . example : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/HBycm)**

style attribute can be set from class and removed from HTML.

```
.statisticWrapper {
  float:left;
  border:solid;
  margin-bottom:25px;
}
.barWrapper {
  width:494px; 
  height:250px;
  line-height:275px;
  text-align:justify;/* spread evenly */
  background:lightgray repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0 , transparent 24px, gray 24px, gray 25px);
}
ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 50px 0 0;/* add padding on right, left has got an empty pseudo element using that much space */
  list-style-type:none;
  height:100%;
  line-height:1em;
  box-shadow:0 15px  15px gray
}
ul:before {/* handy once you have nothing up to 100% :) */
  content:'';
  padding-top:275px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}

ul:after {/* triggers justify like in flex model by adding a virtual line */
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:0px;
  padding-right:50px;
}
li {
  width:40px;
  display:inline-table;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  background:lightgreen;
  padding-bottom:25px;
  position:relative;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px;
}
li span {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  background:green;
}
.h10 {height:10%;}
.h20 {height:20%;}
.h30 {height:30%;}
.h35 {height:35%;}
.h40 {height:40%;}
.h50 {height:50%;}
.h60 {height:60%;}
.h70 {height:70%;}
.h80 {height:80%;}
.h90 {height:90%;}
.h100 {height:100%;}

/* extra , demo purpose to center X,Y body*/
html {
  display:flex;
  min-height:100%;
}
body {
  margin:auto;
}
```

---

free interpretation of your chart possible through CSS and **static** position:[image: barchart from li]

Comment: Hey man, do you know where to find decent lessons (or books) on PSD to HTML+CSS?