# CSS3 - text-align: justify not working on data-hover

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation block made of a list with links. I wanted all the links to be the same length with "text-align:justify" which works fine. I also wanted to add a hover effect on thos links, using CSS3 transformations and data-hover. That works too. The effect is basically making the same word translate from the bottom pushing the original word out of scope. This is done through data-hover (the data-hover specifies the content that comes into view). My problem is that I can't get to justify that content. I can change it's color, size, anything, I can even make a "text-align:right" for example, and it works, but the text-align: justify won't.

So here is the HTML:

```
<nav class="cl-effect-5">
    <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a><span class="fulljustify" data-hover="C&nbsp;O&nbsp;L&nbsp;L&nbsp;E&nbsp;C&nbsp;T&nbsp;I&nbsp;O&nbsp;N">C O L L E C T I O N</span></a></li>
        <li><a><span class="fulljustify" data-hover="A&nbsp;R&nbsp;T&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I&nbsp;S">A R T   I S</span></a></li>
        <li><a><span class="fulljustify" data-hover="S&nbsp;H&nbsp;O&nbsp;P">S H O P</span></a></li>
        <li><a><span class="fulljustify" data-hover="A&nbsp;B&nbsp;O&nbsp;U&nbsp;T">A B O U T</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.fulljustify { text-align: justify; text-transform: uppercase; }
.fulljustify:after { content: ""; display: inline-block; width: 100%; }

ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
nav a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.35em;
    width: 100%;
}
span{
    width: 100%;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.cl-effect-5 a {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1.35em;
}

.cl-effect-5 a span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.cl-effect-5 a span::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: inherit;
    color: yellow;
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline-block;
    content: attr(data-hover);
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.cl-effect-5 a:hover span,
.cl-effect-5 a:focus span {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

I have created a jsfiddle so you can see more clearly what the result that I'm looking for is:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lngvv5hq/

Why, if I can text-align:right the data-hover, doesn't the text-align justify work ? Any way to get it done ? If I can't do it through text-align:justify, do you happen to have any suggestions of other ways to achieve the result that I'm looking for ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: could you try this style="text-align: justify" in your code span tag and let me know if it works

Comment: @Mirza it doesn't work, you can try your guesses on the jsfiddle directly :) thank you anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably came across [this post about justified text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589590/text-align-justify-inline-block-elements-properly) in your research, and Ilya summarized that post quite nicely.

I took another approach at your menu, drawing from Dennis' suggestion about `letter-spacing`. Still, that's a tough pony to ride as your shortest word ("Shop") means that every 1px in `letter-spacing` means adding 4px horizontal width to your text. Likewise, "Collection" adds 10px of horizontal space for each 1px in `letter-spacing`. With these "multipliers" as a constraint, the words will be tough to match exactly in width.

Here's a **Fiddle demo**:
http://jsfiddle.net/erlingormar/ymgobrx2/2/

(In the initial process of identifying the justified-problem, I changed the approach with your data-hover attribute (added a `span`) just to be sure that it wasn't causing the problem):

Comment: Thank you for this. And didn't it work when you tried to justify the span instead of the data-hover ?

Comment: I am trying to change the pixels into %, for the responsiveness, but it seems that letter-spacing doesn't handle %. Any guesses on that ?

Comment: I didn't have any luck justifying the text in the SPAN elements, but then again I didn't go knee deep in workarounds. The problem is that the SPANs only take up one line of text, and a one-liner (similar to the last line in a long paragraph of justified text) won't justify and occupy the entire line length... according to browers' current behavior.

I thought of the responsive aspect of using letter-spacing, but figured you'd probably have so set some breakpoints in your design so that you'd really only have to define perhaps 3-4 letter spacing values. Yeah, it's not all that great.

Comment: Aight i'll bootstrap a few breakpoints then, or just switch to totally different, more mobile-friendly, navigation menu for smaller devices. Thank you ! (this is my first question asked, should I change the topic to answered or something ?)

Comment: No, you don't need to really... having a marked answer that helped you with your problems is good enough Good luck with your project! :)

Answer (score 1):

By default, `text-align: justify` doesn't justify the last (or the only, as in this example) line of text in the block. Justification of the spans themselves works only because of the hack with 100%-wide `::after` pseudo element that always wraps to the new line. Microsoft introduced `text-align-last: justify` (currently adopted by CSS Text Level 3 spec and [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last) by Firefox with `-moz-` prefix), but WebKit-/Blink-based browsers still don't support it.

Comment: I see. Well as the justifying of text is supposed to be bad practice in web dev I guess it will be long before they implement it in all browsers, maybe never haha. Thanks for the intel !

Answer (score 0):

text align don't work this way bro, for now you can use  word-spacing for all menus separately..

for ex:-

```
word-spacing: 46px;
```

will be best for **COLLECTION**

Comment: This is not how I wanted it to be done but hey it achieves the result. I'll probably switch the px to % for the responsiveness. Thank you !

Comment: yes use % and u can target li using nth-child, right ??

Comment: since all the lines need different values of letter-spacing I'll just make a class for each I guess edit: it doesn't work with % haha

Comment: you can use li:nth-child() selector instead of making classes for all li items