# Parent div expanding in height even though child has no height

Tags: html, css

When forcing a line of text or inline-elements to be justified within its parent by adding an `::after` rule, I noticed that the parent will expand in height, to fit the pseudo-element, even if I try to prevent it:

```css
.test {
    background-color:#ccc;
    text-align:justify;
}
.test:after {
    display:inline-block;
    content:'';
    width:100%;
    height:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">test 1 foo bar</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4d7mr5t/

Here's what I tried so far and what it got me (in order of increasing despair):

- `height:0` on the pseudo-element: no change
- `line-height:0` on the pseudo-element: no change
- `overflow:hidden` on the pseudo-element: no change
- a combination of 2 or all of the above: no change
- negative margin or padding on the pseudo-element: no change (negative padding is invalid as far as I know, but at that point I began to become desperate)
- `white-space:nowrap` on the pseudo-element: no change
- `white-space:nowrap` on the parent: broke the layout
- `position:relative;top:-100%` on the pseudo-element: no change
- `position:absolute` on the pseudo-element: broke the layout

Any suggestions other than giving the parent a fixed height or using flexbox?

Comment: Problem and solution at the following link:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589590/text-align-justify-inline-block-elements-properly

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. The solution is not as nice I would've liked (it's actually just a hack to work around specifying an explicit height), but it'll have to do as there is apparently no nice cross-browser solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to solve justifying one line of text is setting height and line-height:

```
.test {
    background-color:#ccc;
    text-align:justify;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
}
.test:after {
    display:inline-block;
    content:'';
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I meant *explicit* height, sorry for the poor choice of words, but my question has been answered in the comment below it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem relates to `display: inline-block` on the :after pseudo element. Since it is an inline item, you also see some effects from white-space. If you change it to `display: block`, everything works as expected.

Comment: `text-align:justify` obviously doesn't work on non-inline elements (I tried it anyway in case I was mistaken). So no, it doesn't work.