# How do I justify inline-block elements inside a <div>, inside a <td>?

Tags: html, css

I have searched for hours and couldn't find a fix to my problem, finally decided to sign up and ask (woohoo, first question). Here is my situation, I have this in my html markup :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="width:800px;text-align:justify;">
                <input style="width:101px;" />
                <input style="width:101px;" />
                <input style="width:101px;" />
                <input style="width:101px;" />
                <input style="width:101px;" />
                <input style="width:101px;" />
                <input style="width:101px;" />
                <input style="width:101px;" />
                <input style="width:101px;" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Basically, this will be generated by an ASP.Net user control that I am designing at the moment (I don't think it is relevant). But whatever I do, I can't seem to be able to get the images to get justified in the final content. Is it possible that the fact I inserted them in a table cell is not allowing the justified style to function properly?

Before you ask, I tried the display:table / display:table-cell on  and  trick, didn't work as well.

Also, I am developing with pure Javascript for client side scripts and I don't want a solution involving jQuery (if at all possible). I would prefer simple and elegant html/css.

Comment: Can you use flexbox ? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: possible duplicate of ["text-align: justify;" inline-block elements properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589590/text-align-justify-inline-block-elements-properly)

Comment: "I can't seem to be able to get the images to get justified " - What images?

Comment: a mockup image of what you are looking for could help here.

Comment: The [inputs are justified](http://jsbin.com/fomolaraka/1/edit?html,output) when I run that code. Possibly what you expect justified to mean isn't what it actually means (i.e. that space between each element should be adjusted so that they are evenly spaced across the entire row, except for the last row which should be left aligned). What effect do you expect to get?

Comment: Also the math doesn't seem to work. 9 * 101 = 909...which is more than 800.

Comment: I'm looking at the link provided right now. It seems to fit my problem. What would be the generated markup for my problem?

Comment: Which link? There are three in the comments so far. What do you mean by "generated markup"?

Comment: The width of the div doesn't fit all the inputs. The width of the inputs combined is bigger than the width of the div which is 800px. Why don't you set the width of the div to auto: **width: auto;**?

Comment: I think this is what the OP is after - http://jsbin.com/mexaheqoce/2/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Paulie_D I know, it's on purpose so that the box doesn't fit and the elements have space between them. Otherwise, they would "look" justified, but end up simply perfectly aligned to the right edge.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn oops, the original markup had type="image" and src attributes, I removed them for privacy

Comment: @Paulie_D it worked!!! but I don't understand why it works. Could you comment quickly (if you have time) ?

Comment: See the linked duplicate question mentioned - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589590/text-align-justify-inline-block-elements-properly

Comment: @Paulie_D my bad, it didn't. I had inadvertently put the width of inputs back to 100px. It still doesn't work. I will try to post an image to show what I mean.

Comment: [current result](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img661/7946/Rirtu2.png) I have tried @Paulie_D 's trick, it didn't work. I want all images to spread out and align perfectly. I KNOW justify is the way to do it, I used text-book justify methods. I think it might not be working because of the table. What do you guys think?

Comment: We really need to see what you are after...do you have a design image?

Comment: In all fairness, I can't seem to reproduce the problem in JSBin...

Comment: Like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/yrcnfm18/

Comment: Ok, the plot thickens... Here is the problem that I manage to reproduce [JSBin of the problem](http://jsbin.com/wekukozoho/3/edit?html,css,output) . You will notice that <input> tags are all stuck one against each other ?? if I put a line break right after them, it gets correctly justified automatically... that's crazy right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lovely people, I found my answer. It's really simple too. My code published earlier was not the real one and. Here it is :

```
<table>  
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="width:800px;text-align:justify; border: solid 1px red;">
                <input style="width:101px;" /><input style="width:101px;" /><input style="width:101px;" /><input style="width:101px;" /><input style="width:101px;" /><input style="width:101px;" /><input style="width:101px;" /><input style="width:101px;" /><input style="width:101px;" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I apologize to those that tried to help me without this information. The thing is the "justify" style works by spreading out the spaces in a text or, in the case of inline-block, the spaces between blocks. ASP.Net generated my code in a block without inserting my spaces. Result is that I have a very long "word" of elements without any space breaks at all! And obviously, "justify" doesn't know how to work with that.

So the code should be corrected to include new lines or spaces at least.

Thanks to everyone again! Sorry for the trouble again. I'll post with more info next time.