# Flexbox space-between behavior using table model

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm currently trying to emulate the flexbox `space-between` layout using the table model. Basically, I have a table that is set to `100%` the width of it's container, cells that have a fixed pixel width and I would like the `border-spacing` to "fill" the space remaining. So far, setting the table's `width` to `100%` overrides the fixed width of the cells and this is not what I want.  Is this even possible?

I'd obviously prefer to use a true flexbox to do this, but the project I'm working on must work on older versions of IE so that is not an option.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.**

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589590/text-align-justify-inline-block-elements-properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add empty table-cell elements between the real cells. Those empty cells will grow to fill the available space.

```css
/* Tabular displays */
.table        { display: table;      }
.row          { display: table-row;  }
.cell, .space { display: table-cell; }
/* Widths */
.table                { width: 100%;  }
.cell                 { width: 100px; }
.cell ~ .cell         { width: 150px; }
.cell ~ .cell ~ .cell { width: 200px; }
/* Borders */
.table { border-collapse: collapse; }
.cell  { border: 1px solid;         }
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">100px</div>
    <span class="space"></span>
    <div class="cell">150px</div>
    <span class="space"></span>
    <div class="cell">200px</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">100px</div>
    <span class="space"></span>
    <div class="cell">150px</div>
    <span class="space"></span>
    <div class="cell">200px</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!
I'm a bit concerned about the semantic implications of having empty elements in the markup but that will have to do.