# Evenly spaced fixed-width columns - in a responsive setting

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create some evenly spaced columns (an `ol`), with the columns themselves being fixed width.

So far, I've managed to achieve the desired effect by using `table` layout, and nesting an additional element inside the list item.

**HTML:**

```
<ol>
    <li><div></div></li>
    <li><div></div></li>
    <li><div></div></li>
    <li><div></div></li>
    <li><div></div></li>
</ol>​
```

**CSS:**

```css
ol {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
}

div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

This [works great](http://jsfiddle.net/gDws8/), but has the following 2 shortcomings:

1. As you can [see in the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gDws8/), the first & last columns don't line up flush with the parent's outer edges.
2. This can't really be used responsively. The only thing you can do at smaller widths is [stack them](http://jsfiddle.net/gDws8/1/), but I'd like to split them (2 or 3 per row).

---

Is what I'm after even possible in CSS alone? I know there are a plethora of ways to accomplish this in JS, but I'm after a CSS-only solution.

---

**P.S.** I don't care about IE7-, but I do need to support IE8. CSS3 selectors are OK though, since I'm anyhow using [`selectivizr`](http://selectivizr.com/) in the project (I know that's JS ;-)).

Comment: I don't quite follow point #1. Do you mean the gutter between the edge of the `div` and the `iframe` border?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - Correct. There's some space between the left edge of the parent container and the left edge of the first column. Same goes for the last column, in reverse.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - The `ol`. Yes.

Comment: I see no space between the frame edge and the li edge, in firebug.  If I squish the frame width down to make 500px, there is no extra space either.

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions - See [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cZPQE.png) for what I mean with the extra space. The `li` does line up flush with the parent, but since the `div` is centered within the `li`, it's not aligned with the edge of the `li`.

Comment: I see it; I just wanted to nail down what "parent element" was literally referring to.

Comment: Just wondering, why aren't you using a grid system? Are you DYI or do you see this as an exercise? (Which I think is an interesting exercise.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I'm not aware of any grid system that could do this. If I were, I'd study their code...

Comment: Which ones have you studied? I've got a list, we can compare notes.

Comment: That probably came off the wrong way. What I meant was, I've been building up a list but a lot of them I don't know much about their capabilities in reality.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - The regular suspects: [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), [RGS](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/), [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/), [Gridpak](http://gridpak.com/), [CSS Grid](http://cssgrid.net/) etc. These are all trying to solve the regular grid structure, which doesn't help me much.

Comment: I thought this one might fit: http://thecolumnist.info/ But it's not responsive. I saw one the other day, but I sometimes forget to bookmark all the ones I want to.

Comment: What is the layout philosophy you're working towards? You're not interested in the candy bar to tongue depressor effect, it sounds like. A collapsing box maybe?

Comment: This one starts off a little like your demo, but planks into a garage door close in: http://www.stacklayout.com/mockups/mockup1.html

Comment: @JaredFarrish - The Stack Layout's columns are not fixed width.

Comment: Oh ok. I see. Even up to 2k screen width?

Comment: Do you think embedding a fixed grid within a flex grid could work?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - Not sure what you're trying to say, but that sounds eerily similar to what I actually did.

Comment: Yes, except that I'm talking about trying it in some of the full-blown grids. The only thing is how to replicate the grouping at lower widths.

Comment: And when I first saw those `div`s, I was wondering what was going on, but I see what you're having to do to get the layout you want.

Comment: I don't know if I'm on to something here or not, but this is *almost* equilibrium: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gDws8/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems appropriate for you to recycle ["how to *really* justify a horizontal menu"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49536/1081234). Basically the behaviour you're describing is that of inline-block elements of identical width having `text-align:justify` applied:

```
ol {
  /*force the desired behaviour*/
  text-align: justify;
  /*remove the minimum gap between columns caused by whitespace*/
  font-size: 0;
}

li {
  /*make text-align property applicable*/
  display: inline;
}

/*force "justify" alignment that requires text to be at least over 2 lines*/
ol:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/RwU2N/1/).

**NB:** you may have to re-apply desired `font-size` and `text-align` to descendants of `ol` depending on the reset you're using (i.e. to prevent these properties from being inherited)

Comment: +1 Very nice demo. This solves problem 1, but still provides no way to split the lines on narrower widths.

Comment: @JosephSilber: how about just removing the `min-height`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok my first thought would be to use media queries to gain a responsive approach for how many you want to show per row on differing screen sizes and my second would be to use

```
     box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
```

this will stop the paddings you may put in later adding onto the box model size.

Hope this is close to what you are after.