# Is it possible to display dividers on hover using only CSS?

Tags: css

Using the technique from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2444135/2730823), I have a nice justified menu bar.

However, I would like to add dividers between the entries which appear on mouse hover.

[My first attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/FtVM7/9/) turned out quite terrible:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Item
        </li>
        <li>
            Menu
        </li>
        <li>
            Link
        </li>
        <li>
            Asdf
        </li>
      </ul>

        <span></span>
</div>
```

```
#menu {
    text-align: justify;
    background-color:gray;
    padding:5px;
}

#menu * {
    display: inline;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    color:white;
}

#menu ul {
    padding-left:0px;
    margin:0px 100px;
}

#menu span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

#menu li:hover {
    color:blue;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
```

The problem with the above is that the borders are not centered between the menu entries.

This is certainly doable with javscript, but I would like to know if it's possible with pure CSS.

Comment: FYI your HTML is malformed. You have no `</ul>` tag and `<span>`s are not valid as children of `<ul>` elements

Comment: And... your css is broken. `#menu li { ... font }` is incomplete

Comment: I think we are all smart enough to fix the issue and to give @gandalf3 the feedback that is necessary without pointing out trivial mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the technique you choose isn't able to fill the entire space with the elements just make a distribution. If you don't have to support IE7 or lower I suggest to go with the `table-cell` solution then the `border` can work the way you want:

```
#menu li {
    display: table-cell;
    width:1%;
    color:white;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nP9gy/)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do to fix this is to add padding in your li.

```
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    color:white;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Then in your hover call the same padding but also

```
 #menu li:hover {
     color:blue;
     border-left:1px solid black;
     border-right:1px solid black;

 }
```

Problem with this is it creates a slight dither in the other nav items. So you can add -1 margin to fix that if you care to. This is what I think you are going for. If I am not correct elaborate more on your issue.

Here are the edits with the input i received.
I also included a transition.

```
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    color:white;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-left:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-right:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

Hover state

```
#menu li:hover {
    transition: border-color 0.5s ease;
    color:blue;
    border-left:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border-right:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

Thank you Dieodius

Jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/FtVM7/10/

Comment: ...or you can just add a transparent border to the non-hovered state.

Comment: That would work as well, to. Thank you for pointing that out.