# Justify spacing between li

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists, justify, adjustment

Please take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

I'm trying to justify the spacing between those two li's to be constant at 35px, It's a WordPress menu, here's the code for the menu:

```
<style>
.main-navigation li {
   margin: 0 0px 0px 40px;
   position: relative;
}
</style>

<li id="menu-item" class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa "></i><span>حملات</span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536/how-do-i-really-justify-a-horizontal-menu-in-htmlcss ?

Comment: Is this all the related code for this?

Comment: @Huangism Actually I can't get all of the WordPress menu code here.

Comment: @OmarSoliman I feel you can spot what's wrong by inspecting the element. Given the above info it would be very hard to know exactly what's causing the extra space

Comment: @Huangism I guess that when the text in the span tag increases the spacing between the li increases, Is there's anyway to avoid that?

Comment: @OmarSoliman Oh is that how that's setup, if so you could set a fixed width for the items